# Matrix Transpose Understanding

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a 3x5 matrix, $B$ is a 3x4 matrix, then

$AX = B$ has a solution iff every **column/row** of the matrix $B$ is in the **column/row** space of matrix $A$?

$X^TA^T = B^T$ has a solution iff every **column/row** of the matrix $B^T$
is in the **column/row** space of matrix $A^T$?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Please edit your post to include some of your thoughts.

Comment: You seem to be copying verbatim an assigned exercise.  This involves two problems.  Please tell your Readers in your own words what the connection between these two parts is.